# Trouble encountered when attempting to build a project in Visual Studio 2022 using C++ for the Sapera Teledyne Delta SDK

Tags: c++, image-processing, camera, sapera

I have a C++ code from the Sapera LT SDK user manual that acquires images from a Nano camera and displays them live. The problem arises when I attempt to build a project in Visual Studio 2022, as I encounter numerous errors.

**I have provided below the steps outlined in the manual to build the project.**
(I have followed these steps meticulously, but I am still encountering issues during the build process.)

Sapera LT ++ - Creating an Application
The following sections describe how to create a Sapera LT ++ application in Visual C++
2013/2015/2017/2019.

Visual Studio 2013/2015/2017/2019
Follow the steps below to compile and link an application that uses the Basic Classes:

•      Include SapClassBasic.h in the program source code (it includes all other required headers)
•      Add $(SAPERADIR)\Classes\Basic and $(SAPERADIR)\Include in Project | Properties | C/C++ |
General | Additional Include Directories
•      If you are building a 32-bit application, insert
$(SAPERADIR)\Lib\Win32\SapClassBasic.lib in Project | Add Existing Item …
•      If you are building a 64-bit application, insert
$(SAPERADIR)\Lib\Win64\SapClassBasic.lib in Project | Add Existing Item …
•      In Project | Properties | C/C++ | Code Generation | Runtime Library, choose the option
Multi- threaded DLL (in release mode) or Multi-threaded Debug DLL (in debug mode)

Follow the additional steps below to compile and link an application that uses the GUI Classes:

•      Include SapClassGui.h in the program source code (it includes all other required headers)
•      Add $(SAPERADIR)\Classes\Gui in Project | Properties | C/C++ | General | Additional Include
Directories
•      If you are building a 32-bit application, insert
$(SAPERADIR)\Lib\Win32\VS2013\SapClassGui.lib (or
VS2015/VS2017/2019) and
SapClassGuiD.lib in Project | Add Existing Item …
•      If you are building a 64-bit application, insert
$(SAPERADIR)\Lib\Win64\VS2013\SapClassGui.lib (or
VS2015/VS2017/2019) and
SapClassGuiD.lib in Project | Add Existing Item …
•      In Project | Properties | General, select Not Set for Character Set
•      In Project | Properties | General for SapClassGui.lib, select Excluded From Build for
Debug
•      In Project | Properties | General for SapClassGuiD.lib, select Excluded From Build for
Release

---

**Here is the code that I am using.**

````
```
#include "SapClassGui.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "SapClassBasic.h"

// Transfer callback function is called each time a complete frame is transferred

void XferCallback(SapXferCallbackInfo* pInfo)
{

// Display the last transferred frame
SapView* pView = (SapView*)pInfo->GetContext();
pView->Show();

}


// Example program
int main()
{

// Allocate acquisition object 
SapAcqDevice* pAcq = new SapAcqDevice("Genie_M640_1", FALSE); 
// uses camera default   settings
//new SapAcqDevice("Genie_M640", "MyCamera.ccf");//loads configuration file

// Allocate buffer object, taking settings directly from the acquisition 
SapBuffer* pBuffer = new SapBuffer(1, pAcq);

// Allocate view object to display in an internally created window 
SapView* pView = new SapView(pBuffer, (HWND)-1);

// Allocate transfer object to link acquisition and buffer 
SapAcqDeviceToBuf* pTransfer = new SapAcqDeviceToBuf(pAcq,pBuffer, XferCallback, pView);

// Create resources for all objects 
BOOL success = pAcq->Create();
success = pBuffer->Create();
success = pView->Create();
success = pTransfer->Create();

// Start a continuous transfer (live grab) 
success = pTransfer->Grab();
printf("Press any key to stop grab\n");
getch();

// Stop the transfer and wait (timeout = 5 seconds) 
success = pTransfer->Freeze();
success = pTransfer->Wait(5000);
printf("Press any key to terminate\n");
getch();

// Release resources for all objects 
success = pTransfer->Destroy();
success = pView->Destroy();
success = pBuffer->Destroy();
success = pAcq->Destroy();

// Free all objects 
delete pTransfer;
delete pView;
delete pBuffer;
delete pAcq;
return 0;
}

```
````

However, I am still encountering errors when attempting to build the project. I have experimented with different types of Visual Studio projects, such as empty project, console app, and Windows app, but each attempt results in errors.

```
 Build started at 15:59...
 1>------ Build started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Debug 
 x64 ------
 1>Source.cpp
 1>C:\Program Files\Teledyne 
 DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\SapClassGui.h(36,1): error C1189: 
 #error:  The 
 project option "General | Microsoft Foundation
 Classes" must be "Use MFC in a shared DLL"
 1>(compiling source file 'Source.cpp')
 1>Done building project "Project1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
 ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 
 skipped ==========
```

After that, I changed the option from 'Standard Windows Library' to 'Use MFC in a Shared DLL' in the properties,and built the project again. Then, I encountered the following problems:

Error   C2504   'CRectTracker': base class undefined    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   16
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'CRect'    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   21
Error   C3646   'm_LimitRect': unknown override specifier   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   24
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   24
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'CWnd' Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   35
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'CWnd' Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   36
Error   C2535   'CImageWnd::CImageWnd(SapView *)': member function already defined or declared  Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   36

Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'CPoint'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   40

Error   C3646   'TranslateMousePos': unknown override specifier Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   41

Error   C2059   syntax error: '('   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   41

Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   41

Error   C3646   'TranslatePos': unknown override specifier  Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   42

Error   C2059   syntax error: '('   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   42

Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   42

Error   C3646   'UntranslatePos': unknown override specifier    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   43

Error   C2059   syntax error: '('   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   43

Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   43

Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'CPoint'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   54

Error   C3646   'GetPixelString': unknown override specifier    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   58

Error   C2065   'pBuffer': undeclared identifier    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   58

Error   C2275   'SapBuffer': expected an expression instead of a type   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   58

Error   C2065   'CPoint': undeclared identifier Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   58

Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'point' Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   58

Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   58

Error   C3646   'GetPixelString': unknown override specifier    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   59

Error   C2059   syntax error: '('   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   59

Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   59

Error   C3646   'GetSelectedRoi': unknown override specifier    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   64

Error   C2059   syntax error: '('   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   64

Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   64

Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'CRect'    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   65

Error   C3646   'ValidateRoi': unknown override specifier   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   77

Error   C2059   syntax error: '('   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   77

Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   77

Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '*'    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   82
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   82
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   82
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '*'    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   83

Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   83

Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   83

Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '*'    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   84
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   84
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   84
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '*'    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   85
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   85
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   85
Error   C3646   'm_ViewRect': unknown override specifier    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   88
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   88
Error   C3646   'm_roi': unknown override specifier Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   90
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   90
Error   C2039   'm_nStyle': is not a member of 'CSapRectTracker'    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageWnd.h   61
Error   C3646   'm_rcInView': unknown override specifier    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   69
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   69
Error   C3646   'm_rcAnchors': unknown override specifier   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   70
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ',' before '['    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   70
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   70
Error   C3646   'm_penROI': unknown override specifier  Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   72
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   72
Error   C3646   'm_brushROI': unknown override specifier    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   73
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   73
Error   C3646   'm_penAnchor': unknown override specifier   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   74
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   74
Error   C3646   'm_brushAnchor': unknown override specifier Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   75
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   75
Error   C2504   'CStatic': base class undefined Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   82
Error   C2144   syntax error: 'CImageExWnd' should be preceded by ';'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   86
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   86
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'CPoint'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   116
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'CRect'    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   117
Error   C2535   'void CImageViewportWnd::SetROI(void)': member function already defined or declared Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   117
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'CPoint'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   125
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'CRect'    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   126
Error   C2535   'void CImageViewportWnd::GetROI(void) const': member function already defined or declared   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   126
Error   C3646   'GetPixelString': unknown override specifier    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   131
Error   C2059   syntax error: '('   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   131
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   131
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'CPoint'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   146
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'CPoint'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   150
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'CPoint'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   153
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'CPoint'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   154
Error   C3646   'TranslatePointToNativeView': unknown override specifier    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   168
Error   C2059   syntax error: '('   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   168
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   168
Error   C3646   'TranslatePointToDestinationView': unknown override specifier   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   169
Error   C2059   syntax error: '('   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   169
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   169
Error   C3646   'GetDstRectFromCurrentScalingOptions': unknown override specifier   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   172
Error   C2059   syntax error: '('   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   172
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   172
Error   C3646   'afx_msg': unknown override specifier   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   180
Error   C3646   'BOOL': unknown override specifier  Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   180
Error   C3646   'OnEraseBkgnd': unknown override specifier  Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   180
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   180
Error   C2059   syntax error: '('   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   180
Error   C2144   syntax error: 'void' should be preceded by ','  Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   181
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ')' before ';'    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   181
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   181
Error   C2144   syntax error: 'void' should be preceded by ';'  Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   182
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   182
Error   C3646   'BOOL': unknown override specifier  Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   183
Error   C3646   'OnMouseWheel': unknown override specifier  Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   183
Error   C2059   syntax error: '('   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   183
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   183
Error   C2144   syntax error: 'void' should be preceded by ';'  Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   184
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   184
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'CPoint'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   184
Error   C2144   syntax error: 'void' should be preceded by ';'  Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   185
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   185
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'CPoint'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   185
Error   C2144   syntax error: 'void' should be preceded by ';'  Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   186
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   186
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'CPoint'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   186
Error   C2144   syntax error: 'void' should be preceded by ';'  Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   187
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   187
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'CPoint'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   187
Error   C3646   'BOOL': unknown override specifier  Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   188
Error   C3646   'OnSetCursor': unknown override specifier   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   188
Error   C2059   syntax error: '('   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   188
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   188
Error   C1003   error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation   Project1    C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Gui\ImageViewportWnd.h   188

If you know of a better way to build this project or can simplify the steps to build and run it without errors, or even suggest modifications to the code, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What errors? Please edit and paste those error messages.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! We cannot help with your problem without
seeing the errors you are encountering and the build command that
produces them. Please copy the complete build log of the failing
build from your IDE and post the text (not a picture of the text)
in your question. That will contain the relevant info. Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78179621/edit)
button to update your post.

Comment: @MikeKinghan  Thanks. I edited my post and provided the errors in the building. I hope that helps, and I appreciate your assistance. If you need more details, I'm happy to provide them for you.

Comment: @kiner_shah  I edited my post and provided the errors in the building. I hope that helps, and I appreciate your assistance. If you need more details, I'm happy to provide them for you.

Comment: @BehradB, please format the error messages and your code properly. Please copy-paste properly so that formatting is retained after paste.

Comment: @kiner_shah I edited my post again and pasted the errors and code once more. If you still have issues with the formatting, please let me know how I can correct it.

Comment: @BehradB, nopes, doesn't look proper. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

A simple suggestion first. The documentation you have quoted:

> - Include SapClassBasic.h in the program source code (it includes all other required headers)
> - Add $(SAPERADIR)\Classes\Basic and $(SAPERADIR)\Include in Project | Properties | C/C++ | General | Additional Include Directories
>
> Follow the additional steps below to compile and link an application that uses the GUI Classes:
>
> - Include SapClassGui.h in the program source code (it includes all other required headers)
> - Add $(SAPERADIR)\Classes\Gui in Project | Properties | C/C++ | General | Additional Include Directories

suggests that `SapClassBasic.h` should be `#include`-ed *before* `SapClassGui.h`. But your program has them the other way round:

```
#include "SapClassGui.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "SapClassBasic.h"
```

This would lead to compilation errors if some class `GuiThing` defined in `SapClassGui.h` (or in a header file `#include`-ed
by `SapClassGui.h`) is derived from another class `BasicThing` that is defined in `SapClassBasic.h` (or in a header file `#include`-ed
by `SapClassBasic.h`), and the compiler cannot accomplish the definition of `GuiThing` because the definition of `BasicThing` is
not yet known.

Read your very first compilation error and you will see that it is of that sort.

So try:

```
#include "conio.h"
#include "SapClassBasic.h"     
#include "SapClassGui.h"
```

and see how your build goes.

It doesn't really matter where `conio.h` goes.

I am not wholly convinced that any of the existing compilations errors will be eliminated by this move. If not,
I may have further input.